# Bind item object in ItemTemplate in MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin, bind, mvvmcross, converters

I am developing an MVVMCross multi platform app and I'm having the following trouble with Converters:

I have a listView in Android with the following code:

```
<MyProjectName.Droid.MvxCustomViews.MvxListView.MvxDroidListView
    android:id="@+id/historicList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Historics;"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/historiclistitem" />
```

Where, Historics is a List.
Then, I have in the layout resource:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/historicIcon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            local:MvxBind="AssetImagePath UpdateType, Converter=HistoricTypeToSource" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listHistoricType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Anexo"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            local:MvxBind="Text UpdateType, Converter=HistoricTypeToString" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listHistoricTypeDetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Anexo adicionado"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        local:MvxBind="Text ???, Converter=HistoricDetailsToString" />
```

The problem is, everything is working fine, but in the listHistoricTypeDetail's TextView's bind I need to pass the entire object, because, depending on each Historic.Action, I will add a text that uses Historic.AdditionalParameter, Historic.NewValue, Historic.OldValue!!!

I'm not figuring out how to pass 3 parameters depending on the value of the bind to the converter, or how to bind the entire object so my converter would be like:
MyConverter : MvxValueConverter

Is that clear? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the complexity of your conversion, I think it's probably easiest to pass the entire object which you can do just by using a single period:

```
    local:MvxBind="Text ., Converter=HistoricDetailsToString"
```

or - using Tibet-syntax - as:

```
    local:MvxBind="Text HistoricDetailsToString(.)"
```

---

I think the wiki article may also help: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding

e.g.:

> If `$SourcePath$` is omitted or a single period "." is used, then the Source used is the whole of the ViewModel.

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#swiss

Comment: Was exactly that what i needed! Thanks Stuart for the quick answer!!